# fill datagridview with content from .mdf

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, mdf

I am trying to fill a datagridview with content from  a `.mdf` SQL Server database file (C# Windows Forms app)...

```
private void Companies_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   load_table();
}

void load_table()
{
            String DATA = Application.StartupPath + @"\data.mdf";
            string constring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=" + DATA + ";Integrated Security=True";

            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("select * from Companies ;", conDataBase);
            try
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
                DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dbdataset);
                BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

                bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
                sda.Update(dbdataset);
            }
            catch (Exception uu)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(uu.Message);
            }
        }
```

I get nothing. DataGridView is empty. No errors...

Table name: `Companies` with 4 rows and 1 column...

I tried SQL statements like

```
select * from dbo.Companies ;
```

... still nothing

I changed `data.mdf` connection to full path c:/etc/etc ...

No luck.

Any simple solution is welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.mdf` is a **SQL Server** data file, therefore you need to use the **SQL Server** client library, e.g. `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter`.

What you're using now (`MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand`, `MySqlDataAdapter`) is for *MySQL* and won't work on a (Microsoft) **SQL Server** data file.

Comment: Thanks for that. I just deleted all "My" before sqlconnection command etc... And it worked! Thanks again.